# How to increase the snowpipe warehouse size

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I know that snowpipe uses internal warehouse snowpipe.

However there is a requirement where I will be needed to load big single file like 30GB of size using snowpipe (continuous data ingestion, Files arrive in S3 once every week but any time).

And we do not have control to split file or change format.

Is there a way that I can define snowpipe warehouse size to large or XLarge.

or if not then what should be the best way to handle this scenario so that the file is loaded faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snowpipe operates no differently from running a COPY command directly.  The size of the warehouse has NO effect on the speed at which a single file will load.  The benefit of a larger warehouse is the number of files that can be loaded in parallel, which is why the best practice is to split your files into smaller pieces.  If you truly have no ability to split the files (or create a Lambda process that splits your files that land on S3 for you), then you have no control on how fast that file will load into Snowflake.

I would explore whether you're able to run a command using Lambda or some other scripting that would split a file that lands on S3 into multiple files and places those smaller files into the Snowpipe S3 bucket.  If you can do this, Snowpipe will load the files in parallel and be far more efficient for you.

Comment: I am not very sure about this. I tested and your statement seems incorrect to me. Please correct me If I am missing something. I loaded a 7gb single file using snowpipe and it took 13 min. Now l tested loading the same file in different table manually with warehouse size XLarge and it completed in 7 min. So technically warehouse size matters even loading a single file

Comment: Have you tried loading that same single file on a XS warehouse?  A COPY INTO only leverages a thread per file.  So, an XS warehouse has 8 threads, so a COPY command will only use 1 of those.  If you use an XL, it'll still only use 1 of the 128 threads that an XL has.  There won't be any difference assuming that there are available threads on the warehouse to run those.  If you are finding that Snowpipe is slower than what you are seeing on COPY commands (single-file!!!!) than I'd recommend a Support ticket to explain why that is the case.

Comment: Something more is going on.. I can confirm I tried loading a 13 GB file with Xsmall , run for half an hour only 10 percent was done, so I abort the query. Next I reran the same copy with same file with Large warehouse and copy completed in 20 min.

Comment: Could you share your COPY statement?  Are you doing a lot of casting or other transformation logic in it?  Your file is larger than our recommended size and if you are doing a lot of transformations, you could be creating some extra work that a smaller warehouse doesn't handle well.  The suggestion there would be....don't do that.  Load the data into a transient table directly and then run the transformations directly in Snowflake.  This gives you (a) a faster ingestion in Snowpipe or other, and (b) more control over the warehouse size needed to do the transformation step.

Comment: And, the total time of the 2 steps will be less than the 1 step process you are doing now....assuming that you have transformation logic, of course.

Comment: Yes I am doing Some transformation.. Like concat all the col. and doing md5($1||$2||$3).. and reading the medata$filename etc.. So If I dont do all this in Copy and instead use a staging area and then later update the record , will it be faster

Comment: Yes - it'll be much faster to load it first and do the transformations afterwards.  You'll also be able to load it with Snowpipe or an XS warehouse without issues.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I removed the transformation, Now instead of 16 min the snowpipe took just 7 min. After that I am going to upgrade the task warehouse size to XLarge and do the transformation of the table there using task and stream

Answer (score 0):

Snowpipe uses Snowflake-supplied compute resources, so no there is no way to set the size of the warehouse.